# Populating spinner with available wifi addresses

Tags: android, spinner, android-arrayadapter, android-spinner

I am working on making a spinner display a list of wifi SSID that are available. I use the following to store the SSID into a string array in my onReceive of my Broadcast Receiver.

```
List<ScanResult> wifiScanList = mainWifiObj.getScanResults();
        wifis = new String[wifiScanList.size()];
        for (int i = 0; i < wifiScanList.size(); i++) {
            wifis[i] = ((wifiScanList.get(i).SSID));
        }
```

How would I then display the wifis array to my spinner? I have my spinner object in my xml, and in my onCreate I have

```
sp = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner);
```

and in my broadcast receiver I try to do this...

```
ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,
wifis, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
```

but since my array isn't a resource, it does not work. I've been looking for other ways to do it, but all I come across is how to access a string from an xml file.

So my question is, how do I use my existing code to then populate a spinner with a list of my wifi choices. Thank you for any help.

**EDIT:** Complete code now works:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

WifiManager mainWifiObj;
WifiScanReceiver wifiReciever;
ListView list;
Spinner sp;
String wifis[];

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    sp = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner);
    mainWifiObj = (WifiManager) getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
    wifiReciever = new WifiScanReceiver();
    mainWifiObj.startScan();
}

protected void onPause() {
    unregisterReceiver(wifiReciever);
    super.onPause();
}

protected void onResume() {
    registerReceiver(wifiReciever, new IntentFilter(
            WifiManager.SCAN_RESULTS_AVAILABLE_ACTION));
    super.onResume();
}

class WifiScanReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @SuppressLint("UseValueOf")
    public void onReceive(Context c, Intent intent) {
        List<ScanResult> wifiScanList = mainWifiObj.getScanResults();
        wifis = new String[wifiScanList.size()];
        for (int i = 0; i < wifiScanList.size(); i++) {
            wifis[i] = ((wifiScanList.get(i).SSID));
        }

        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(MainActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, wifis);
        adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        sp.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following:

```
List<ScanResult> wifiScanList = mainWifiObj.getScanResults();
    wifis = new ArrayList<String>();
    for (int i = 0; i < wifiScanList.size(); i++) {
        wifis.add(((wifiScanList.get(i).SSID)));
    }

ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, wifis);
adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Comment: It says the constructor ArrayAdapter<String> is undefined

Comment: try changing `this` to `getActivity()`. Are you using a Fragment?

Comment: I'm dumb, I just switched it to MainActivity.this instead of this, and it got rid of the error, let me check if it works.

Comment: Switch `wifis` from and array to an `ArrayList<String>`